# Rotate 'Card' 180deg along Y axis

Tags: jquery, css, css-transforms

I have got this mostly working (see https://jsfiddle.net/90ycrope/1/) however the content in the second div with the word 'behind' is visible throughout.

The two goals I am trying to achieve are:

1. Correct function (behind content visible behind, front content visible at front)
2. Efficiency - I would imagine the code has a more simplistic approach?

**HTML:**

```
<div class="box_holder">
<div class="front">Some content here</div>
<div class="back">Behind</div>
</div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.box_holder').click(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('show_info')
  });
});
```

**CSS:**

```
.box_holder {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    left: 8px;
    top: 8px;
    width: 240px;
    height: 335px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family:'ProximaNova', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: normal;
    background: #C3C3C3;
    color: #3b3b3b;
    font-size: 1em;
    line-height: 1.32;
    margin-right: 16px;
    margin-bottom: 32px;
    transition: 1s;
}
.box_holder.show_info {
    -ms-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
.box_holder.show_info .front {
    -ms-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
.box_holder.show_info .back {
    -ms-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
.front {
    backface-visibility:hidden;
    transition:1s;
}
.back {
    transition:1s;
}
.show_info .back {
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is a minimalistic and fixed version of the flip animation. The following is what I have done:

- Applied only the height, width to the container and added `position: relative` to it.
- The front and back elements are positioned absolutely with respect to the box_holder container and the background, color are applied to these child elements.
- The `backface-visibility` of the child elements are set to hidden. This is the **key property** as it prevents the backside of the element from showing up.
- Initially the front element is not rotated but the back element is rotated in Y axis by 180 deg. This sends the back element behind and it becomes hidden due to the setting mentioned above.
- When the element is clicked on and the show_info class is applied, the rotation on back element is nullified (rotated back to 0 deg) while the front  is rotated in reverse direction by 180 deg. These two together make it look as though the container is being flipped.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.box_holder').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('show_info')
  });
});
```

```css
.box_holder {
  position: relative;
  width: 240px;
  height: 335px;
}
.box_holder .front, .box_holder .back {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  background: #C3C3C3;
  color: #3b3b3b;
  transition: 1s;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}
.box_holder .back {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
.box_holder.show_info .back {
  transform: rotateY(0deg);
}
.box_holder.show_info .front {
  transform: rotateY(-180deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js"></script>
<div class="box_holder">
  <div class="front">Some content here</div>
  <div class="back">Behind</div>
</div>
```

**Note:** Use of prefix free library is only to avoid adding prefixed versions which bloat up the code.

Comment: Hi Harry , could you please check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41276905/processing-backwardundo-and-forwardredo-option-using-jquery